# MySQL Algorithm vs Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

You find a lot of info on this online. But not what the exact work around of the use of Algorithm is in MySQL. The real basics, if you will..

What a query is, is obvious, of course. What Algorithm does, remains unclear.

Main reason for this question is: to improve profiling & matching records to known users. (In this case: to match docs in a database to users that need them)

Some examples of the usage of it are highly appreciated!

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking and talking about...

Comment: **what algorithm does, remains unclear** what algorithm..? Algorithms in general? a simple google would tell you exactly what an algorithm is. https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-GsGVNSGKMHH8gfEuoLwDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=what+is+an+algorithm

Comment: The question seems very clear to me, which is why I voted to re-open it.  `Algorithm` has a very well defined meaning in MySQL.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't that clear to some of you. But the answer below got me started in the right direction and I've been working and learning all day so far. So, sorry if it wasn't that clear, and thanks Gordon for picking it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Algorithm` is a keyword used with `create view` in MySQL.  The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html) does a pretty good job of explaining it.

The short answer is that MySQL supports two methods of handling views:  either "merging" the view definition in the calling code or creating a temporary table.  The first is called `MERGE` and the second `TEMPTABLE`.  In general, `MERGE` is faster, but most views are `TEMPTABLE` because of the restrictions on `MERGE.